# Defining structs in C after main() function

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have learned a decent amount of java and now I want to learn C, I've learned a little about structs and typedefs but I have errors when I place the typedef after the `main()` function and it is used from within the `main()` function.

Is there a way to declare types but not define them in C so I can keep my code after the `main()` function similar to functions? (I'm not sure if this is good practice but I like organizing my code this way)

Comment: Read a good book on C, such as [modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Study for inspiration existing open source code in C (e.g. on http://github.com/ or http://gitlab.com/ ...). See also [some C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and glance into  [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Be aware of the [C preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. C code is intended to be read by the compiler and it will learn about new definitions as it keeps reading the file. Moving things below `main()` serves no purpose. It will also confuse other humans.

As for the question itself: in some cases, yes, you can. If everything you need is a forward declaration, you can do so. But in most cases you will want the definition, so it won't help you.

For example, this will compile:

```
struct T;

int main(void)
{
    struct T * p = 0;
    return !!p;
}

// Later on you may define `struct T`
```

Answer (score 1):

C requires a type to be declared before it's used.  If the code is just using a pointer to the type then the code doesn't not need to declare the members, this is a forward declaration.  Other usage, such as passing the type by value or using it as a local variable requires a full definition.

C projects generally use headers which will provide the definition of types.  These are included into the C modules.

```
// header.h
#ifndef _header_h_
#define _header_h_

struct DescribedType {
    int member;
    char* variables;
};
#endif

// module.c
#include "header.h"

struct ForwardDeclaration;
ForwardDeclaration* allocForward();

int main(){
    DescribedType someType;
    ForwardDeclaration* someValue = allocForward();
    return 0;
}

struct ForwardDeclaration {
    int declaredLater;
};
```

Comment: The header guard for `header.h` is wrong (assuming that is what you intended!). Also note that usually files/translation units/etc. are rarely called modules in C (and it does have a concrete meaning in C++ nowadays).

Comment: Doh!  Overlooked the define on the header guard.  Thank you for pointing that out.

I am familiar with C source files being referred to as modules from the 90s and early 2Ks, thank you for letting me know the term has since changed.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, some people use that term, but it hasn't changed, it was never an official one.